# How to switch among items in AlertDialog?

Tags: android

I'm creating an `AlertDialog` with setting array (`R.array.select_dialog_items`) of items to it:

```
<string-array name="select_dialog_items">
    <item>Start</item>
    <item>Stop</item>
    <item>Delete</item>
</string-array>
```

I don't know how to switch among these items in `onClick()` method, can you advice?

```
public void init() {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setTitle("Task");
        builder.setItems(R.array.select_dialog_items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                switch (item){
                case : // How to iterate here?
                }
            }
        });
        alert = builder.create();
    }
```

Comment: @Lumis what do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int item` of the `onClick` method represents the position of the item clicked in the alertDialog (as mentioned in the API [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnClickListener.html). Therefore:

```
public void init() {         
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);         
builder.setTitle("Task");         
builder.setItems(R.array.select_dialog_items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {             
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {                 
switch (item){                 
        case 0: // Start item
           some code...
           break;

        case 1: // Stop item
           some code...
           break;

        case 2: // Delete item
           some code...
           break;
}            
 }         
});        
 alert = builder.create();     }
```

Give that a try.